# Predicting using adanet for binary classification problem

Tags: tensorflow, predict

I followed the tutorial of adanet:
https://github.com/tensorflow/adanet/tree/master/adanet/examples/tutorials
and was able to apply adanet to my own binary classification problem.

But how can I predict using the train model? I have a very little knowledge of TensorFlow. Any helps would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately call [`estimator.predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator?version=stable#predict) on a new unlabeled example and get a prediction.